# Sophisticated TypeScript inference

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a code:

```
interface Cat{ meow:boolean }

interface Zoo{ bobtail:Cat, bengal:Cat, cheetoh:Cat }
```

then, somewhere in code:

```
let cats:Zoo;// imagine it's set correctly somewhere
for(const i in cats)
   if(cats.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        const creature=cats[i];
        /// well, the "creature" is of type "any" here...
   }
```

Of course I could do `const creature:Cat = cats[i]` here, but is it possible to make TS guess that it can't be anything except Cat? I mean, since I always rely on type inference, sometimes I may not notice things like this. Is there maybe a way to either make it more strict or is there any best practice for cases like this one? Thank you.

Comment: It's not possible. It can be other things than cats. When you say `cats:Zoo`, you're saying that the `cats` object must implement *at least* `Zoo`. It can implement other interfaces and have other attributes, that may not be `Cat`s.

Comment: That's not correct. It is not "at least". The reason TypeScript is fine with writing something like `let cats:Zoo` is that `let` allows for later initalization of the variable. If, at a later point, you want to assign something to `cats` it *has to satisfy* the interface. And because the members are not optional, an assignedment hast to set all three. Doing something like `cats = { bobtail: { meow: true } };` is not allowed.

Comment: @SebastianSebald: The problem is not assigning the properties to satisfy the interface. The problem is that the object can provide additional properties that are of a different type. And when you don't create the object in your code (eg. when you deserialize it from JSON) you have no guarantee at all that the interface will be satisfied.

Comment: @Sefe Yes. I just want to correct the "at least" statement. You can actually see that already in the authors code. The `Zoo` interface is using `hasOwnProperty` even though he never defined it ;)

Comment: @SebastianSebald: As I said, if `cats` comes from JSON (or a simple cast from `any`), it is actually possible that some of the properties of `Zoo` are undefined (or of a different type).

Comment: @Sefe As I said, my comment was refering to the first comment. It wasn't about your (correct) answer or the type assertion used by the author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript can not guarantee you that all the properties will be of type `Cat`.  The object `cats` can have more properties than defined in the interface and their type is unknown at compile time. Only at runtime it can be determined which property the object has and what their type is.

You have three options to assert the type `Cat`: Type casts, type guards and hashmap types.

**Type cast**

When you are sure that *all* the properties of `cats` are of type `Cat`, you can simply cast your result into `Cat`:

```
let cats:Zoo;// imagine it's set correctly somewhere
for(const i in cats)
    if(cats.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        const creature=cats[i] as Cat;
        ///the "creature" is of type "Cat" now...
    }
```

**Type guards**

If you are not sure if all properties of `Cats` are of type `Cat`, you can use a type guard. That will only consider the values with the correct type:

```
//Define type guard
function isCat(value: any): value is Cat {
    return value.hasOwnProperty('meow');
}

//...

let cats:Zoo;// imagine it's set correctly somewhere
for(const i in cats)
    const creature=cats[i];
    if (cats.hasOwnProperty(i) && isCat(creature)) {
        ///the "creature" is of type "Cat" within the block...
    }
```

**Hashmap types**

Depending on your requirements, you can replace the `Zoo` interface with a hashmap type, that allows an arbitrary number of entries (or properties if you wan to call them like that) of type `Cat`:

```
type Zoo = { [key: string]: Cat };
let cats:Zoo;// imagine it's set correctly somewhere
for(const i in cats)
    const creature=cats[i];
    ///the "creature" is of type "Cat"...
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that you can not set specific property names, as you do with the interface in your example. As of TypeScript 2.2 this syntax is *not* allowed:

```
type Zoo = { ["bobtail" | "bengal" | "cheetoh"]: Cat };
```

In many cases this is no problem though and in this solution you don't need any additional steps like casts and type guards, since the type can be inferred.